# Removing an iPhone from the iCloud device list without removing it from Find My

Tags: security, find-my-iphone

I had an iPhone which was stolen a while back. It's remained on my account ever since, but I flagged it as "lost" in the Find My app in the hopes that this prevents the thief from wiping the phone or gaining access to any of my data. In my account settings, this phone is still shown as logged in, but unable to receive verification codes.

I'm now trying to set up Advanced Data Protection on my new iPhone. It tells me that to do so, I must  update or remove the other iPhone (the one marked as stolen) from the trusted devices list on my account.

If I remove the device from my account via `https://appleid.apple.com`, does it stay on my Find My devices list in lost mode?

On a side note, it also does make sense that once the device is stolen, there should be a way to remove the device from "trusted devices" as it's no longer a trusted device, without also removing its activation lock...